# Object is used but not declared?

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I have the following VHDL code, its a entity of a project:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
library work;
use work.typedef.all;

entity uc is
    port(faaaa: in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
          phi: in std_logic;
          isDirect,isRam,jmp,store,NarOut,arpOut:out std_logic);
    end entity uc;

architecture b8 of ua is
    signal   instt : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    signal bit7: std_logic;
        begin
            bit7<='0';
            instt <= faaaa;
            ....
            process(phi) is
            ....
            end process;
end architecture b8;
```

The error says that:

> object "faaaa" is used but not declared

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This error message is specific to a synthesis/simulation tool. Can you please add it's name as a tag so others can search for this message.

Comment: @Paebbels, it's a Quartus message [ID: 10482](http://quartushelp.altera.com/14.0/mergedProjects/msgs/msgs/evrfx_vhdl_is_not_declared.htm).  Somewhere there's been analyzed an entity `uc` that doesn't have the declaration of `faaaa` found in architecture uc(b8).  The entity `ua` with the declaration isn't being used in the architecture shown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your entity is called `uc`, but the architecture `b8` is of `ua`.

Comment: ... which means that `faaaa` is declared somewhere else, and not visible inside this architecture.